# Self hosted WCF service not responding after several hours of being idle

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2012, self-hosting

I have hosted WCF service in a console application which is expected to run 24/7 and respond to requests from several applications. It works great if it gets requests continuously or even after 4 hrs of idle time. The code written to host the service is given below,

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(abcdService)))
        {
            host.Open();
            Console.ReadLine();
            host.Close();
        }
    }
```

In the WCF service, I was writing the output to console. When it throws the timeout error, I could see that the method in WCF service never received a request.

Is there any settings I need to do to make the self hosted WCF service respond to simple calls even after several hours of idle time?

The error I received is given below,

The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9989999. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. ---> System.TimeoutException: The HTTP request to '' has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out. Aborting test execution.

Note: When I restart the console application hosting WCF service, it starts to work fine again.

Comment: show config, implementation, client code, service contracts

Comment: I am having the exact same issue with a self hosted service. During normal usage and under heavy load tests it works fine, but sometime during the night - when nobody uses it it somehow crashes and I can no longer access it from my client app / browser. Did you find the cause to your problem?

Comment: Not yet. But we are doing a workaround to reduce the occurrence of problem. Basically, we are restarting the console application (.exe) everyday midnight via a windows scheduler. This reduced the crash count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requests might be queuing up on server before they are handled and then times out.

1) Try [throttling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms735114%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in your WCF services.

2) Try using [PerCall](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b927dcf2-0e0a-4b56-9a26-e2f8df333c62/per-call-vs-per-session-instantiation) Use the following to remove the Session in your interface

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="namespace", SessionMode=SessionMode.NotAllowed)]
```

Contract class implementing interface

```
ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
```

You should be able to enable tracing to see exactly what is occurring.